# Generating multiple java Enums from a single table, using JOOQ

Tags: java, jooq

I have a table in my database schema which contains configuration information for an application that I'm building. I'd like to generate a number of enums based on the contents of the table. I'm currently using JOOQ in my build scripts to generate other, standard JOOQ classes from the same database, and am hoping that I can obtain this new functionality through JOOQ.

For example, if the table contained the following data

```
Product        Component    PresentationOrder
HydroProduct   Boat         1
HydroProduct   Canoe        2
HyrdoProduct   Ship         3
LandProduct    Car          1
LandProduct    Bike         2
```

Then I'd want to generate two enums

```
hydroProduct.Components { Boat, Canoe, Ship; }
```

and

```
landProduct.Components {Car, Bike; }
```

where hydroProduct and landProduct are packages, and the enums are both called Components.

The precise details are up for grabs (e.g. I'd be fine with different naming conventions, so any suggestions are welcome), but the principal (two enums from the one table, based on the data therein) is, at least for this question, the thing that I need.

Having read the JOOQ docs, I see that generating Enums was once a part of JOOQ, and then removed. I can't see the "obvious" way of doing what I want in JOOQ, but it's a pretty amazing library, so I'm guessing that there might be one.

**EDIT**

A number of commenters have questioned the overall approach, which I understand. I'd like to avoid that kind of conversation - it's basically impossible for me to debate that level of design over this forum. This approach (code generation based on DDL and SQL) is very well tested within my organisation, and has had a very large amount of design scrutiny.

Just for the record, here's an outline the pipeline. I'm putting it in because I appreciate that people have spent time considering my original question, and I'd like to make it clear how the question fits into our overall dev system.

Project One holds some bootstrapping classes, some DDL and some SQL scripts that contain the data constants that our overall system uses. It's output includes (amongst other stuff), some .jar files containing compiled versions of classes generated. These basically comprise the core agreed vocabulary that the rest of our system uses to communicate.

Project Two holds java source code, which makes use of the various artefacts generated from project one. Before project two ever gets compiled, artefacts from project one can be assumed to have been generated. So, for example, an Enum generated from data held in project one can be used, at compile time, in project two.

Our build scripts build project one, and make the outputs available for project two. This includes generating Eclipse project files so that users of project two can check-out, build, and open eclipse for any branch of the project and it "just works".

There are other projects (including in different languages, e.g. Javascript) that also make use of the artefacts generated by project one.

The key benefit of this approach is that, when the data in project one changes, and the definitions of classes and enums in project one therefore change, project two reflects this change with compile-time errors, rather than run-time errors. The benefits of this in practice are absolutely enormous. There is a setup-cost, yes, but in our experience tools like JOOQ (which we use to generate the outputs of Project 1) have made us incredibly more productive than we used to be.

This is especially the case where we ship desktop, in-browser, and J2EE components and they all need to talk together.

Comment: `enum`s should be compile-time constants, so generating them based on data from a DB is IMO problematic; what if someone inserts a new value or deletes an existing one after you've released your software?

Comment: @Mick: at some point, there has to be a decision made about where canonical constants are defined. The DDL is as much a part of my source code as the Java files. Since I already have a bunch of Java classes being generated from the DB, and then compiled, the database lives "upstream" from my java source - so I define those constants in the database. If someone adds or deletes an existing row in the DB, then the database and code are no longer compatible. This is also true if someone adds a constant to the enum in the source.

Comment: I can understand the DDL being "part of the source", because it describes the _structure_ of the tables. However, I think the actual _data_ should be treated differently; if data in a given table should not change between versions of your software, why keep it in the DB at all when you could store it in a property file, for example?

Comment: I am agreeing with the notion that Java enums were intended to allow you to enumerate a group of constants, all of which are known at compile time.  Dynamically generating a group of enum constants is not something that would naturally occur to me.

Comment: Yours is a completely valid viewpoint. I made the choice I made because I judged that (a) the database and the Java source have to agree on a set of constants, (b) the best way to encode that agreement was to encode them as data in the database, and enums in Java, and (c)  databases are the best tool I know to manage data. With those three assumptions (and they are just my assumptions), the best course of action is to use the database to define the constants, and derive the enums in Java. Adding a third place to define the constants (like a property file) is less appealing to me.

Comment: This should be a cache than `enum`. How will your other source codes make use of this enums that just do not exist during compile time?

Comment: @MickMnemonic: It certainly helps distinguishing between "ordinary data", and "master data", the latter being more closely part of the meta data (DDL) rather than the user data. It's a thin line, of course, but assume that master data changes very rarely, just like DDL...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't be an exhaustive answer, as the question is a bit opinionated, but I can provide some authoritative background on the history of this feature in jOOQ:

> Having read the JOOQ docs, I see that generating Enums was once a part of JOOQ, and then removed.

Yes, the reason for removal was precisely because the then-existing implementation was far from sophisticated enough to accommodate, for instance, your particular use-case.

Code generation is a very ad-hoc "science" and it is extremely difficult to maintain a configuration API backwards compatibly, which can accommodate all the possible use-cases... For instance, the fact that you want to map parts of your master data onto packages, class names being constant, ordering custom is rather particular, not generic.

Furthermore, where should generated enums be referenced from? The original implementation replaced foreign keys (e.g. Integers) by enum references in the generated code. This might not at all be what you want in some cases, where you do want to join the master data in its raw form, not as a generated enum.

Long story short, this was an eagerly added feature in jOOQ 1.x, which was extremely hard to maintain during major internal refactorings that were needed to create jOOQ 3.x, [which is why it was dropped](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/reference/migrating-to-3.0/).

> I can't see the "obvious" way of doing what I want in JOOQ, but it's a pretty amazing library, so I'm guessing that there might be one.

Not out of the box. I'd recommend using a templating language like [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org) or [Xtend](https://eclipse.org/xtend/documentation/203_xtend_expressions.html#templates) and generate the code manually as part of your build. You could, in fact, even generate custom [`Converter` or `Binding`](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-bindings/) implementations to bind your enums to the relevant referencing columns.

Comment: Thanks for the references. Would you see Velocity and/or Xtend sitting upstream or downstream of JOOQ? (I'm guessing downstream, so that the Velocity/Xtend generated classes can reference the JOOQ generated classes...? Anyway, thanks heaps.

Comment: Actually, considering this further, I think you must mean upstream, because then they can be used in bindings. (I'm also not sure what you meant by your first sentence above - opinionated? But thanks for the background.)

Comment: @BurleighBear: ["Opinionated" as according to the faqs](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), i.e. the possible answers are endless. Anyway, it doesn't matter if you generate those enums before or after the jOOQ classes, but you'll probably have to compile them at the same time. Or what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I don't think you're missing anything. I was just meaning that by the time jOOQ is run to generate classes, I would probably want to reference the generated Enums in the Binding definitions for jOOQ, so I'd assume that I'd have had to compile the Enums before running jOOQ. (I may be wrong about that....)

Comment: @BurleighBear: Aha, I see. No you don't have to worry about that. jOOQ's code generator just generates text files that happen to end with `.java`. The compilation happens later on, independently of jOOQ's code generator (or of your enum generator)