# jOOQ: Is it possible to generate enums from certain tables given by a name pattern?

Tags: enums, jooq

Sometimes it is necessary to have tables like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE contact_phone_type (

    -- PRIMARY KEY

    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,

    -- ATTRIBUTES

    name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO contact_phone_type
    (name)
VALUES
    ('Phone'),
    ('Fax');
```

Which are sometimes annoying to map into `enum` types in order to have a convenient and typesafe mapping later on. Since those `enum` types have to be hand written it is sometimes a bit annoying to type the exact same thing a second time. Especially annoying is the case when one changes the ordering. This means that a corresponding email has to be re-ordered by hand as well.

Therefore I am wondering if jOOQs code generator might be able to generate those enums for me instead?

I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31395905/generating-multiple-java-enums-from-a-single-table-using-jooq) but my use case if by far not that tricky.

All the generator would have to do is basically look if e.h. the table ends with `_type`, and if so, create an enum with elements specified e.g. by column `name` and copy those generated files into a directory I am telling it to.

Is there a chance that this is possible?

Another thing that comes up with those enums is that one has also to write corresponding `Converter<>`. If the code generator recognizes a "type-table" then it could create the enum *and* the corresponding converter.

---

Just a toy example:

```
private void createDeliveryPhoneNumber(Long shopId, String deliveryPhoneNumber) {
    this.ctx
        .insertInto(SHOP_CONTACT_PHONE)
        .set(SHOP_CONTACT_PHONE.SHOP_ID, shopId)
        .set(SHOP_CONTACT_PHONE.PHONE, deliveryPhoneNumber)
        .set(SHOP_CONTACT_PHONE.CONTACT_PHONE_TYPE_ID, ContactPhoneType.DELIVERY)
        .execute();
}
```

Comment: Am I understanding this correctly: All you want is replacing the `String` column `name` by a generated `enum` column `name`?

Comment: @LukasEder Well, yes. Any table ending with `_type` is actually a "*well known type*`. So that does never change after the database has been initialized. That way I could use e.g. `ContactPhoneType.DELIVERY` to insert stuff into a table `shop_contact_phone` (see toy example in my question).

Comment: OK, but then, I don't really see how that's different from the other question...

Comment: @LukasEder Well not really imho. The OP from the other question wants to define the ordering of the fields given by their column value `PresentationOrder`. This contract would be more complicated than just read the table line by line. Another thing is that he wants to generate *multiple* enums from one table. I in contrast want just *well known types* to be generated automatically (their enum and their converter). That task would be simpler imho and has a very simple contract: The sole PK "id" sets the ordering and the one and only character string typed column the name of it.

Comment: OK, I see your point of view, although, as the library maintainer, I don't agree with your perception of "more complicated" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31395905/generating-multiple-java-enums-from-a-single-table-using-jooq) but my use case if by far not that tricky.

Apart from the fact that your use-case perception is subjective, and I disagree :), this is equally not available out of the box from jOOQ as the use-case in your linked question (for the same reasons).

It is, however, rather easy to implement this kind of code generation yourself at your end. Either, you can extend the jOOQ code generator to generate additional classes, or you do that in an entirely independent step.

Comment: I tend to underestimate the effort needed for software on a daily basis. Even though I should know it better by now, I am almost never able to make a good estimate for stuff I want to implement - at least when it comes to things that I never did before! :) Okay, it's not the end of the world to not have this feature even though it would be nice to have. Maybe I'll take a look on extending the code generator. :)